# Duplicate a spreadsheet in Excel Online each Monday

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was wondering if anybody knows a way to duplicate an MS Excel Online sheet each Monday. Tried to look into Power Automate but it's limited to adding a new row only, and not even with a schedule/interval. What I'm trying to do is - specify a sheet in the same Excel document and make it be duplicated each Monday.

Answer (score 0):

With this macro it is possible.

The new sheet will get the name from the old one and add the weeknumber.

Add Macros to your file and save as .xlsm file.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 Call CopySheet_Monday
End Sub

Sub CopySheet_Monday()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MySheet As Worksheet
    Dim strMySheet As String
    Dim TodaysDay As String
    Dim NewSheetName As String
    
    'here you specify your worksheet name
    strMySheet = "MyWorksheet"
    
    Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strMySheet)
    
    'the name of the new worksheet. Old Name and weeknumber
    NewSheetName = MySheet.Name & Application.WorksheetFunction.IsoWeekNum(Date)
    
    'Check if new worksheet already exists
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name = NewSheetName Then 'exit sub when it exists
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next ws
    
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        TodaysDay = .Weekday(Date, 1) '1 if first day of week is sunday, 2 if it is monday
    End With
    
    If TodaysDay = 1 Then '1 is monday
        'copy sheet insert at the end
        MySheet.Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = NewSheetName
    End If

End Sub
```